# ERROR, API rate limit exceeded

Tags: api, limit, google-compute-engine, rate

I am new user.  I just create project. After I put my credit card information and enable billing, I get the following error message when I clicked "compute engine". I also wait for few hours and still get same message. Need help..

*ERROR
API rate limit exceeded. Rate limit may take several minutes to update if Google Compute Engine has just been enabled, or if this is the first time you use Google Compute Engine.*

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  "Create Empty Project" fails with "Rate Limit Exceeded" and no further details.